# Can't remove Free Shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, free-shipping

On a 1.9.1 install we've had Free Shipping on orders over a certain amount, but need to remove this.  I've tried everything short of coding it.  All settings in Sys>Config>Sales>Shipping Methods is set to disable.  Free shipping is disabled, Free shipping in USPS, UPS, and FedEx is disabled.

There are no catalog or cart rules that offer free shipping.  I've turned everything off, and set the minimum value for free shipping to be 100,000, but it still shows up on every order over $200.

There's only so many settings that can control this, and they all look correctly disabled.  Anyone run into this?

Edit: I see that the company is using Webshops Matrix Rate to control the shipping.  Even though...its completely disabled in the admin.  The mystery deepens.  I am trying to just code that out of the file displaying it, the search continues.

Answer (score 0):

Did tou clear cache? Because everything which you set under system config is cached inti config cache and if you change anything you need to clear cache under system->cache management....

Edit: I see that the company is using Webshops Matrix Rate to control the shipping.  Even though...its completely disabled in the admin.  The mystery deepens.  I am trying to just code that out of the file displaying it, the search continues.

Comment: Most definitely cleared the cache, flushed it, then flushed the storage.  Re-indexed, and still it just will not go away.

Comment: I have the same problem and have no shipping extensions installed.

Comment: Anyone help me, Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps metrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.

Answer (score 0):

Shipping Matrix has a bug, the problem went away when the module was removed.